# How do shared_ptr react when assigned a new variable?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

Hello members of stackoverflow,

I'm currently trying my hands on c++ (been mostly programming in C#) and was wondering about memory management when using shared pointers.

I have a class that basicly reads in a bunch of variables from a textfile:

```
constructor(string file){
//..do stuff with file

s = new string(valuefromfile);
array_i = new int{value1, value2}
}
private:
shared_ptr<string> s;
shared_ptr<int*> array_i;
```

As far as i understood, sharedpointers help with memory allocation/leaks, since the allocated memory will be freed once all pointers are no more, without me having to deallocate them by hand, e.g. calling the classes deconstructor, or if used in a subroutine.

Now my question is

If i read in a new file with the class, "s" and "array_i" will get new values:

```
void readnewfile(string file){
//...do stuff with file
s = new string(newstring);
i = new int{ newvalue1, newvalue2, newvalue3 };
}
```

now the innitial values are not referenced anymore by those smartpointers. Will that mean the memory is freed, or do i have to watch out for something specific to prevent memory leaks?

Greetings

Comment: Shared pointer uses a reference count. If a shared pointer is overridden, the reference count of old contents is decremented (if there is one). If it reaches 0, the pointee is deleted. (I call this "Last one leaving switches the light off."-principle.) However, please, have a look at `std::make_shared()` which is a better replacement for `new` for `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: You shouldn't need smart pointers for this at all.  A `std::string` member and a `std::vector<int>` member should be all you need.  C++ is, IMHO, a lot more complex and nuanced than C#.  If you are new to C++, I suggest you forget about C# and get yourself a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) so you can see the C++ approach to programming, like pointers being really only needed when using polymorphism.

Comment: In modern C++, you should rarely need to use `new` (nor `malloc`).  I haven't used `new` in my current code base since C++11 came out.  `std::shared_ptr` is a lot like the C#/.NET memory management, but in C++ it should be your last "go to" choice, only to be used because you _have_ to use it.  Prefer `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: `new int{value1, value2}` creates **one** integer. If you wanted two, you should write `new int[2] {value1, value2}`. Note that it requires `std::shared_ptr<int[ ]>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scheff for answering my question:

> Shared pointer uses a reference count. If a shared pointer is overridden, the reference count of old contents is decremented (if there is one). If it reaches 0, the pointee is deleted. (I call this "Last one leaving switches the light off."-principle.) However, please, have a look at std::make_shared() which is a better replacement for new for std::shared_ptr. – Scheff

And thanks to NathanOliver for his answer:

> You shouldn't need smart pointers for this at all. A std::string member and a std::vector member should be all you need. C++ is, IMHO, a lot more complex and nuanced than C#. If you are new to C++, I suggest you forget about C# and get yourself a good C++ book so you can see the C++ approach to programming, like pointers being really only needed when using polymorphism. – NathanOliver

Ye, vector is much better than redefining the arrays each time and when i read in a new File myvector.clear(); seems to do the trick without any leaks.